# Dynamic Sitemap created from Content Hub data

Tags: sitecore-api, content-hub, sitemap

So I am already using the built-in sitemap generator that comes with Sitecore 9.3 and that works fine. I am able to get out pages that are in the content tree. The issue comes when my company wants to show the pages that are dynamically created from a static page in the content tree but then uses variables from the CMP to build out the page with service calls. Here are my examples:

**Page in the tree that shouldn't be on the sitemap**

[www.myfakesite.com/product-page](http://www.myfakesite.com/product-page) (isn't an actual page, just use it for some static content)

**Page NOT in the tree that shouldn't be on the sitemap**

[www.myfakesite.com/product-page/pagecode/yearcode](http://www.myfakesite.com/product-page/pagecode/yearcode) (pagecode and yearcode come from data in the content hub and this could be a combination of hundreds of codes and years)

So I need a way to dynamically pull in and create a sitemap entry for these pages and have no clue where to begin. Any help would be great.

Comment: you need to write custom code and get all the "Page" template items below Home item, and create the XML file with these links. I wrote a similar code and this was run periodically which updates all the Site pages. Believe me this is a bit tricky, you need some good amount of time to implement and test

Comment: Ok thanks and was figuring it would be a lot of custom writing. I just was unclear how to run those pages to get the link.